# Distribution for a quotient of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $X$ has a exponential distribution with mean $\theta$. What would the distribution be for $\frac{X}{e^X}$? I'm trying to calculate the probability $P(\log(X)-X+1<c)$ where $c$ is a constant.

Comment: First notice how $x/e^x$ varies as $x$ starts at $0$ and increases. It starts at $0$ and moves upward, but ultimately approaches $0$ as $x$ grows, so it has an absolute maximum. And calculus tells you that the maximum is reached when $x=0,$ so the maximum value is seen to be $1/e.$ So $X/e^X$ takes values in the interval $[0,\,1/e]. \qquad$